# Counterxample enumeration on UPPAAL

Tags: verification, formal-verification, model-checking, ctl, uppaal

Good afternoon, I am doing some experiments with UPPAAL model checker and my understanding is that, when a property is not verified, the verification engine (verifyta) only enables to find *one* among the following:

- A Trace
- Shortest Trace (Number of Transitions)
- Quickset Trace (Trace with shortest relative time).

This makes a lot of sense, if we consider that model checking focuses on soundness instead of completeness and the fact that at least one trace exists that violates a specific property means that that property is not satisfied.

However, in the context of my application, I would need to find more than one counterexample to analyse their structure etc. To this extent, I was wondering if there exist the possibility of extrapolating *ALL* the possible traces that violates a particular property defined in TCTL, given a bounded search space (i.e. limiting the depth of the search graph). Furthermore, if UPPAAL doesn't offer this opportunity, could you please point me to other tools that might have implemented it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: "ALL the possible traces" can be an infinite set if there is a loop in the model.

Comment: Hey mariusm, thanks for your reply. I do realise that but I was wondering whether, given a limited depth of the search - or number of steps in the simulation - , one could enumerate all the counterexample. 

Thanks!

Comment: Uppaal does not have this feature, but it could be worthwhile adding it as a feature request at https://github.com/UPPAALModelChecker/UPPAAL-Meta/issues
I also encountered a similar problem for test case generation, where the limiting factor is the coverage (i.e. report only the traces with novel coverage), so perhaps we'll get some time to implement something like this.